# Filtering a Scala List from Java

Tags: scala

This compiles fine, but blows up at runtime with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.List.filter(Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List

```java
import scala.Function1;
import scala.collection.immutable.List;
import scala.collection.immutable.Nil$;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public class FunProc {
    List nil = Nil$.MODULE$;                      // the empty list
    List<Integer> list1 = nil.$colon$colon(1);    // append 1 to the empty list
    List<Integer> list2 = list1.$colon$colon(2);  // append 2 to List(1)
    List<Integer> list3 = list2.$colon$colon(3).$colon$colon(14).$colon$colon(8); // List(8, 14, 3, 2, 1)

    Function1<Integer, Object> filterFn = new AbstractFunction1<Integer, Object>() {
        public Boolean apply(Integer value) { return value<10; }
    };

    List<Integer> list4 = list3.filter(filterFn); // List(8, 3, 2, 1)

    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Filtered List is " + list4);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

After experimenting with idonnie's answer, I came up with this:

```
List<Integer> list4 = list3.toTraversable().filter(filterFn).toList();
```

This is essentially the same as idonnie's answer, except that instead of casting, conversions are used. I still would like to know why toTraversable() is necessary, given that the following compiles fine:

```
List<Integer> list4 = list3.filter(filterFn);
```

Comment: `::` is prepend and not append

Comment: I looked at list3 in a debugger and it appears to have been constructed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me,

```
$ javac -cp O\:/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar  jfilter/FunProc.java 
jfilter\FunProc.java:19: error: incompatible types
    List<Integer> list4 = list3.filter(filterFn); // List(1, 2, 3, 8)
                                      ^
  required: List<Integer>
  found:    Traversable<Integer>
Note: jfilter\FunProc.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

idonnie's Traversable is ok.

FWIW, the scaladoc shows "Definition Classes", for those of us who are IDE-averse.

This may be a symptom of [inconsistent java generics signature](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3452), with [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-user/NfoCEmWUv6Q) and [analysis interminable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/K2dELqajQbg/gV0tbjRHJ4UJ).

But `scalac -Ycheck:jvm TraversableLike.scala` doesn't complain about filter.  (My comment on that ML thread was "the compiler bails out of addGenericSignature after emitting the warning".  My fix as such was to add a cast in Scala to support interop.)

Comment: Paul Phillips says this is the correct answer, and references https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3452. He knows better than I! Now to try to understand why this answer is correct...

Comment: @MikeSlinn Paul simply meant that the problem is inconsistent java generics signature. For myself, I still can't see *what* is wrong with the type signature that 2.9.2 generates, but it can be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Through `javap`, finally found a filter method in scala.collection.TraversableLike

**EDIT**

Compiles and runs:

```
    List<Integer> list4 = (List<Integer>)
(((scala.collection.TraversableLike) list3).filter(filterFn));
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but why? The compiler finds filter(), or it would not compile. I don't think there is any ambiguity resulting from another filter() in scope, so why is it necessary to cast list3 to a TraversableLike? I can understand the cast to (List<Integer>), because Java just sees an object returning from the filter.

Comment: Maybe someone enlightened could answer this? `AbstractTraversable` <- `AbstractIterable` <- `AbstractSeq` <- `List`, and `AbstractTraversable` has method that returns Object...

Comment: @idonnie Links to a usual suspect in my answer.

Comment: @Mike Slinn, you have "unaccepted" my answer and StackOverflow charged -15 to me??! Can you please un-unaccept it, so I will not worry that I have investigated, answered first - and was charged -15? ^)

Comment: I reached out to Scala-language, where Paul Phillips, author of most of the Scala compiler, stated that som-snytt's answer was correct. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/1BlnDW2XIQs/juhQJO_LZgEJ I confess that som-snytt's answer was so hard to read that I did not accept it at first. It is not that your answer is incorrect, but his is more correct. I appreciate your time. I wanted to know why your answer worked. Turns out the problem I posted about illustrates a known compiler bug. Your answer is not a generic solution for the bug.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about that StackOverflow rule concerning un-accepts )

Answer (score 2):

We can use `FunctionN` and their `AbstractFunctionN` subclasses to perform operations such as `filter()` on Scala Lists from Java. Here is how to create a Scala List and filter it.

```
// List(8, 3, 2, 1)
List<Integer> list4a = list3.toTraversable().filter(filterFn).toList();
```

This technique obtains access to the methods provided by the `TraversableLike` trait in order to invoke `toTraversable()` on the list, which returns a `Traversable<Integer>` instance. `filter()` can then be called, which returns another `Traversable<Integer>` instance. `Traversable` has a method called `toList()` which then converts the `Traversable<Integer>` instance back into to a `List<Integer>`.

I don't understand how the Scala compiler bug that som-snytt refers to is mitigated by the following:

```
// this produces the same result: List(8, 3, 2, 1)
List<Integer> list4b = 
    (List<Integer>) ((scala.collection.TraversableLike) list3).filter(filterFn));
```

`filterFn()` is an instance of the `Function1` subclass `AbstractFunction1`. This instance is defined for Java as `Function1<Integer, Object>`, which means that it accepts an `Integer` and returns an `Object`. The `apply()` method definition, as written in Scala, actually returns a `scala.Boolean`, but Java does `not know about`scala.Boolean`. Instead, we define`apply()`to return a`java.lang.Boolean and the type parameter for the returned value is declared as `java.Object`. **I would like to understand how this works more properly.**

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This all sounds mightly suspicious to me.

First, let me state that the use of traits shouldn't have anything to do with it. When you use traits, Scala creates forwarders to static methods implementing those traits, so calling a method defined by a trait or a class shouldn't make any difference at all.

Second, I don't see a problem with the definition of `filter` as given by `javap`:

```
  public scala.collection.immutable.List<A> filter(scala.Function1<A, java.lang.Object>);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: aload_1       
         2: invokestatic  #1103               // Method scala/collection/TraversableLike$class.filter:(Lscala/collection/TraversableLike;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object;
         5: areturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 76: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       6     0  this   Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
               0       6     1     p   Lscala/Function1;
    Signature: #1104                        // (Lscala/Function1<TA;Ljava/lang/Object;>;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List<TA;>;
```

So the method is there and the type signature seems right. I'd take this issue to the scala mailing lists, though I'm willing to bet there's some issue open already for this.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, will do! I agree that this seems suspicious.